# Struggling to use Sonos/Internet when son playing Fortnite

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a 40Mbps internet connection to my house, so not that fast but fast enough in most cases, I also have a Sonos system that I use all day long to stream radio and Spotify music. Usually it works fine but usually when my son starts playing Fornite on Playstation 4 by Sonos starts failing, either I cant get a connection to the Sonos system at all or the radio keeps cutting out.

Internet browsing also seem slower, although if I do an internet speed test it works fine as if there is no problem.

I have searched on internet for problems when playing Fortnite there doesn't seem to be an issue, but I am sure its Fornite related because when he plays other games such as Fifa everything seems okay.

The Playstation is connected directly to the router in the same room, Sonos booster also connected to router but then Sonos is around the house using wireless, my office has an Ethernet connection to the router but is at the top of the house.

I did install Wireshark to try and see what the network trafficx was but couldnt understand it at all

How is Fornite causing me such issues ?

Comment: There is no way Fortnite is bringing down your network by itself

Comment: I just asked my son to stop playing Fornite, within 30 seconds sonos was working again !

Comment: Something else is going on.  Just a quick google search says fortnight usea about 100mb hour.  You have a 40mbps download speed, so that would take ~20 seconds all at once.  Spread that over an hour...

Comment: Is the PS4 using wireless or cable? What if they play a different online shooter? What if they use a cable to connect the controller to the PS4?

Comment: I realize that fortnite should not cause an issue, but it is the playing of fortnite that is. But just discovered the ethernet cable plugged into the playstation was not actually connected to network so he was using it wirelessly, so could fortnite somehow always take precedence over the wireless network ?

Comment: Ive only noticed problem using Fortnite, its the only online game he plays that much

Comment: my router is a frtitzbox provided by Zen Internet.